# Excel cell matching

Tags: excel, autohotkey

I have an excel file that looks like this:

<kbd>Column A .</kbd><kbd>Column B .</kbd><kbd>Column C .</kbd>
<kbd>Cell 1A</kbd>      <kbd>Cell 1B</kbd>      <kbd>Cell 1C</kbd>      
<kbd>Cell 2A</kbd>      <kbd>Cell 2B</kbd>      <kbd>Cell 2C</kbd>      
<kbd>Cell 3A</kbd>      <kbd>Cell 3B</kbd>      <kbd>Cell 3C</kbd>

I need to make an authotkey script that can search through all cells in a column, such as Column A, and if the value inside the cell matches the value of what's currently in the clipboard (as an example), then I need it to return the value of that row for column C.

So for example, lets say that Cell 3A (which is in Column A), contains the value of 1337, and the clipboard contains the value of 1337. This is a match, and at this point I need it to return the value in Cell 3C (column C).

I don't know how to go about getting AHK to match a value (clipboard or otherwise) to cells in an excel column, or how to make AHK spit out a value, such as Cell 3C, from a cell in an excel file either.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Provide your code and describe where it fails. Elaborate on how your program works: Where does the input come from? What exactly does the input look like? How does it get into the clipboard? You can check for equality like so: `if(varA = varB)`. For Excel automation, have a look into [COM](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/69033-basic-ahk-l-com-tutorial-for-excel/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a little buggy, but here's some code to get you started.  You may need to increase `Sleep` times to make it more reliable.

```
InputBox, Rows, Number of Rows ; 3 in example
Inputbox, Separation, Separation between columns ; 2 in example
Sleep 3000 ; 3 seconds to select 1A in example
clipboard_backup := clipboard
Loop % Rows
{    
    Copy() 
    ; My excel was adding an extra character when copying, this removes any non-characters
    clipboard := RegExReplace(clipboard, "\W", "") 
    if (clipboard = clipboard_backup)
    {
        Send, {Right %Separation%}
        Copy()
        Send, {Left %Separation%}
        Tooltip, %clipboard%
        Sleep 1000
        Send, ^v
    }
    Send {Down}
}
ToolTip, 

Copy()
{
    global
    clipboard =
    Send ^c
    ClipWait, 4
}
```